# Spaces in urls in comments and posts are not parsed

Tags: feature-request, comments

Today when [I tried to write a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169975/unity3d-xcode-debug-logs-not-available-on-device-cant-see-in-console) with a link containing spaces in its fragment (the part after the hash) it did not want to parse. The link was:

```
http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone configuration utility
```

And the code to put it in a comment was:

```
[iphone configuration utility](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone configuration utility)
```

This code in a question doesn't work either:

```
[iphone configuration utility][2]

[2]: [http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone configuration utility]
```

Spaces in the fragment part of the URI might or might not be in the standards, but you see them in use on the web and parsing them should not be that hard.

I was able to fix this manually replacing spaces with `%20`, but this should not be required.

---

Demo - broken in question: [iphone configuration utility][2]

[2]: [http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone configuration utility]

Comment: Demo - broken in comment: (iphone configuration utility)[http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone configuration utility]

Comment: links in comments works like this `[link text](http://google.com)` so square brackets first... [link text](http://google.com)

Comment: And [here is the MSE duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224321/link-in-comment-with-spaces-in-url)

Comment: And it is mentioned in the [Faq - How do comments work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757)

Comment: Demo - [iphone configuration utility](support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone configuration utility) broken in comment (fixed syntax)

Comment: From the links I provided it is clear that this is by design....so not a bug, but you can try to change it in a feature request.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, @rene, i will. Also, sorry for not noticing the duplicate and FAQ entry.

Comment: AFAICT this is a Chrome issue. When you copy from the address bar, it should be automatically encoded. Open your link in another browser, then copy from the address bar and paste it back here to test.

Comment: @Fabrício If I copy that URL into my address bar (Safari) it encodes to include `%20`, when I copy it back out it still contains `%20`.

Comment: @deceze oh, seems like this issue is specific to Chrome and IE. Firefox encodes the URL properly when copying from the address bar as well.

Comment: @Fabrício Indeed, I can reproduce the problem in Chrome. ChanibaL: file a bug with the Chrome and IE people. :)

Comment: reproduced on chrome/osx, not reproduced on firefox/osx and safari/osx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URLs cannot contain spaces. This is by design of URLs. Spaces in URLs must be encoded as `%20`. Your sample URL is not a valid URL to begin with. I think it's unreasonable to expect any software to be able to parse non-standard URLs; standards are for making it possible to use technologies across different implementations consistently.

Since the problem seems to exclusively be caused by Chrome (and IE?) "prettifying" the URL in the address bar and retaining that prettification even when copying the URL from there, please file a bug with the Chrome (and IE) teams. This behaviour is breaking more software than just Markdown.